# Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 CSS files not found it gives missing error. in browser's console and heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-cli, ruby-2.4

I am using a themeforest by asbab. I've added them to my ruby on rails app. It works perfectly fine in localhost. But when uploaded to heroku, the css files are not found. It wont load all the css files.

**Ruby : 2.4.0**

**Rails: 5.1.4**

### Heroku logs

```
2018-05-07T16:43:00.642798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/header.css" host=printorbuy.herokuapp.com request_id=354f10c5-98e6-408a-811a-dac5b5a357f2 fwd="157.32.106.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-05-07T16:43:00.169047+00:00 app[web.1]: [9a3e2628-2587-4ea2-bc24-fb43f88193f4]   
2018-05-07T16:43:00.169098+00:00 app[web.1]: [9a3e2628-2587-4ea2-bc24-fb43f88193f4] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/simple-line-icons.css"):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since all of the assets are masked before deployment check [fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

thus, all of your css are fingerprinted for e.g.

```
/assets/plugins/animate.css
```

must have converted into something like

```
/assets/plugins/animate-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css
```

similarly to all of the other css.

If you want to fix this, you have 2 options

1. disable the asset fingerprinting

   ```
   config.assets.digest = false
   ```

   For more info refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html
2. use scss (its by default with ror), https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

   - change the file name home.css to home.scss
   - change all `url('<file-name>')` to `asset-url('<file-name>')`

Comment: yes actually CSS apply successfully but it gives error so what I need to do after Your 1st option? like clean assets and recompile? can you give steps?

Comment: you just need to add `config.assets.digest = false` in your environment file, thats it. I guess your heroku is running in production so you need to add this in `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask?

Comment: you told in the answer like my CSS is not converted properly so after update production.rb it will be converted (/assets/plugins/animate-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css)?

Comment: No, what I said is you css is getting converted to /assets/plugins/animate-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css, that's why you are getting the errors, with `config.assets.digest = false` your css will not convert.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the asset pipeline to include the CSS file? It should take care of things like fingerprinting for you.

Assuming you have your CSS theme file in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, Rails would autoload it. You have two options, load it into your application.css file, or load it separately using helpers.

Option 1: Loading the CSS file into `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require my_theme
 */
```

Option 2: Loading the CSS file via [Rails helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets):

```
# application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "my_theme", media: "all" %>
```

I also recommend also going over the [Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) section from the official Rails Asset Pipeline guide, it'll help you understand and follow conventions, so you don't have to deal with cases like this.

Comment: Thanks, @omar but I already have the layout called home and I also  Load the CSS file via rails helper

Comment: Could you show us how you're loading the file and your `config/initializers/assets.rb` ?

Comment: i do  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.js home.css )

Comment: Is `home.css` your theme? How and where are you loading the theme?

Comment: I have a home layout under the home folder ii have all the CSS.

Comment: Then I would recommend going into the Rails console (`rails c`) and running `Rails.application.assets.paths` and see if the directory you want is included there, if not, then you probably need to either move it, prefix a missing part of the path in where you include it, or add to your path.